# Put new data to specific keys in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add some data to an existing array without modifying any of the existing keys or values.

The original array is like this:

```
array(
    'sections' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'sections_id',
            'title' => 'sections_title'
        )

    ),
    'settings' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'settings_id',
            'title' => 'settings_title'
        )
    )
);
```

Now I want to be ablle to add new arrays to sections key and to settings key  that will turn the following into :

```
array(
    'sections' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'sections_id',
            'title' => 'sections_title'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'NEW_sections_id',
            'title' => 'NEW_sections_title'
        )           
    ),
    'settings' => array(
        array(
            'id' => 'settings_id',
            'title' => 'settings_title'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 'NEW_settings_id',
            'title' => 'NEW_settings_title'
        )
    )
);
```

I tried using array_push and array_merge without success I hope someone can help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you would do it just like you would any other array.

```
$array['sections'][] = array('id' => 'sec_id', 'title' => 'sec_title');
```

Comment: thnx @Martin that was fast :)